# Querying in MongoDb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have a model named "Class Sessions" with :scheduled_at as one of the fields, i need to extract ClassSessions whose :scheduled_at is later than a specific date.

P.S.: Scheduled_at stores date in UTC format.

Comment: try some thing like `ClassSessions.where(:scheduled_at.gte => Time.now.utc)` where `Time.now.utc` will return the time now in utc format.. note. this will not owork in Vanilla Ruby but will work in rails.

Comment: Thanks a lot Minato !Helped me a lot

Comment: `Time.utc(2000,"jan",1,20,15,1)` this will return the time required but I guess plane UTC won't work. you'll have to call `to_s` on it to convert it to string. but you can always try and check for the results.

Comment: glad could help.. :)

Comment: Just one more, how do i select classsessions between a date range ?ClassSessions.where(:scheduled_at.gte => Time.now.utc and :scheduled_at.lte => Time.now.utc) doesn't seem to work

Comment: `ClassSessions.where(
  :scheduled_at.gte => Time.now,
  :scheduled_at.lte => 10.minutes.ago
)`

Comment: and remember its a `Mongoid#Criteria` object you'll have to call `.results` to get the result set.

Comment: Thanks Minato ,got my results!

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like `ClassSessions.where(:scheduled_at.gte => Time.now.utc)` where `Time.now.utc` will return the time now in utc format..

`gte`, `lte`, `lt` ... etc are the comparisons you're looking here. please refer to [Mongoid Docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/) for further info.

and Rails by default combines all the condition seperated by `,` in where as `AND` so for range use that logic.

**Note: Where returns a `Mongoid#Criteria` Object and you might have to call `.results` on it to return the result set.**

**Note2: you might've to call `.to_s` on `Time.now.utc` before passing it to mongodb where but I am not sure, try doing both if it works without `to_s` don't call that.**

For Time you can have a look at [Ruby Time Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html)